# Is calling Mage::app() in a template file good or bad practice?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento-1, best-practice

I want to get the store code in a phtml file.  I know I can get it with the below.

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()
```

But is this good or bad practice?  My guess is that it is not as `Mage::app()` is firing up the application again, which would be very heavy.  But I see it used a lot, so maybe I'm misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, it's not a good practice.
Templates should not access anything else except methods in the block that renders it.
But M1 is full of `$this->helper` calls or `Mage::app()` calls so I guess you can go ahead and do it.
If the template is from your own module and uses one of your blocks maybe you should create a `getStoreCode` method in the block and use that one.

But just to clarify something...`Mage::app()` does not fire up the whole application again.

the method looks like this:

```
public static function app($code = '', $type = 'store', $options = array())
{
    if (null === self::$_app) {
        self::$_app = new Mage_Core_Model_App();
        //a lot of code here
    }
    return self::$_app;
}
```

So if the application is initialized this method will only return the instance of the application without any other extra processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper and create a function to get store code. You can call helper function in phtml file.